# Calculate a confidence interval for the mean value of y at $(x_1,x_2) = (1.0,2.0)$ with confidence level $0.90$.

Tags: standard-deviation, confidence-interval

Assume a normal linear model for y with two continuous predictors $x_1,x_2$ and no intercept: $y_i=\beta_1x_{i1} +\beta_2x_{i2}+\varepsilon_i,  i= 1,...,n $ You performe a corresponding linear regression on a dataset with n= 20 observations.The estimated parameters were $\hat \beta_1=−10.5$ and  $\hat \beta_2= 2.0$, the residual variance $\hat\sigma^2= 4.0$ and $(\pmb X^T \pmb X)^{⧿1}=
\begin{bmatrix}
8 & -0.3  \\
-0.3 & 0.2  \\
\end{bmatrix}
$,where X is the design matrix.  The first column of X corresponds to $x_1$ and the second column to $x_2$.  Calculate a confidence interval for the mean value of y at $(x_1,x_2) = (1.0,2.0)$ with confidence level 0.90.

ANSWER : To calculate a confidence interval for the mean value of y at $(x, y) = (1, 2)$
with confidence level of 0.90, we can use the following formula:

$CI_{0.90} = \hat y \pm t_{0.05, 19}\sqrt{\hat\sigma^2\pmb X^T(\pmb X^T \pmb X)^{⧿1}\pmb X}  $

where:$\hat y$  is the predicted value of y at $(x_1,x_2) = (1, 2)$, which is given by:
$\hat y =\hat \beta_1 x_1 +\hat \beta_2 x_2 = -10.5\times 1 + 2 \times 2 $

$t_{0.05, 19}$ is the critical value of the t-distribution with 19 degrees of freedom and a significance level of 0.05, which is equal to 1.734.

$\hat\sigma^2$  is the estimated residual variance, which is equal to 4.

$\pmb x$ is the vector of predictors at $(x_1,x_2) = (1, 2)$, which is equal to [1, 2].

$(\pmb X^T \pmb X)^{⧿1}$ is the inverse of the variance-covariance matrix of the estimated parameters, which is equal to
$
\begin{bmatrix}
8 & -0.3  \\
-0.3 & 0.2  \\
\end{bmatrix}
$

Substituting these values into the formula, we get the following confidence interval:
$CI_{0.90} =-6.5\pm 1.734 \sqrt {4.[1, 2]^T
\begin{bmatrix}
8 & -0.3  \\
-0.3 & 0.2  \\
\end{bmatrix}
}[1, 2] =[-11.5, -1.5]$

Therefore, we can be $90%$ confident that the mean value of y at $(x, y) = (1, 2)$ is between $-11.5$ and $-1.5$.

Is the way i have done is correct ?I am confused in the value of $t_{0.05, 19}$, it will be 18 or 19 degree of freedom?